# Connect active mq using openwire protocol

Tags: go, activemq-classic

Does anybody has an example how to connect `ActiveMQ OpenWire` protocol using go please?
I used `stomp & amqp with ActiveMQ` for now and both are ok (testing), but our it architect will probably push for OpenWire as almost all our applications are Java based and that is standard for our company. So I would be happy for nay example, suggestions  how to do it and not loose go service only because `OpenWire` protocol

thanks

Comment: I hope this would help you: https://godoc.org/qpid.apache.org/electron

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ActiveMQ OpenWire documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/openwire.html). It has a link to a handful of Java classes which are used to generate C, C#, C++, & Java client code. You could probably use those as examples to create your own files to generate Go client code which can speak OpenWire.

That said, you're probably better served by using the Go AMQP or STOMP clients as ActiveMQ was designed to be used by multiple protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answers. I agree with ***stomp & amqp*** as sufficient for task and agree that write ***OpenWire*** client just for sake of it is not good option. I have to convince our architects now

Answer (score -1):

AMQP and OpenWire clients can co-exist and is by far the best solution for you, even though you have a Java-stack.

Your second best bet is to write some glue code in Java/C#/C++ that connects an OpenWire AMQ client with something that GO can speak to (like another ActiveMQ using AMQP or STOMP ;-) ).

If you really really really need OpenWire support, the best bet is to try to use the [C++ client](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/index.html) and call it using [swig](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Go.html) or whatnot.

Writing a native OpenWire-client in Go is a major effort and there is no point, except as a "fun" task.